# Get digits before the decimal point for big double numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to create an application that will return the three last digits before the decimal point of a double number.
In the below example, the outcome should be 006.

```
  double number = 6.578336356630531E15;
  int num = (int) number % 1000;
  String output = String.format("%03d", num);
  System.out.println(output);
```

But the result is : 647

But for the following with the same approach the outcome is correct:
Should return 006.

```
  double number = 6.57833;
  int num = (int) number % 1000;
  String output = String.format("%03d", num);
  System.out.println(output);
```

Result now is correct: 006

So I guess that the problem has to do with the very big number in the first example? But I need to deal with such big numbers.

Any explanation why this happened?
Cheers.

Comment: If you have to deal with such numbers, use `BigDecimal`. The problem here is not the range (7e15 is far from being the maximum a double can represent) but the precision.

Comment: It is unclear what you want, because the number 6.578336356630531E15 is the same as 6578336356630531, so the last three digits before the decimal point would be 531, not 657, not 647 and not 006

Comment: But 647 is what java return.

Comment: @fge I will try now the BigDecimal.

Comment: @fge BigDecimal throws overflow exception when I am trying to convert the number to int using .intValueExact()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the below example, the outcome should be 006

No. It should be 531, the last three digits of the value `6578336356630531`.

But `6578336356630531` is alnmost certainly too large to fit into a `double` without loss of precision. A `double` only has 53 bits of precision, which is 15.9 decimal digits.

And casting that value to `int` is going to cause further truncation and loss of precision.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Apokai answer solve my problem, but thank you anyway for taking time to explain my error.

Comment: Basically, you are right, using long rather than int not working again. But the exercise I have to solve asking this kind of thing. It is possible to have such big number, and my program should return back 3 digitis before the decimal point

Comment: Finally, I saw some hints for the exercise and said that, the number can't be stored in a double variable, and we should use a mathematical concept called conjugation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using long, as your conversion INT takes precedence on the modulo and you are loosing precision:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     double number = 6.57833;
      int num = (int) number % 1000;
      String output = String.format("%03d", num);
      System.out.println(output);

       number = 6.578336356630531E15;
       long num2 = (long) number % 1000;
       output = String.format("%03d", num2);
      System.out.println(output);
}
```

Worked for me. Gave me 531, which is the last 3 digits. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I tested now and the output of num2 is 6578336356630531 so won't work either.

Comment: You are sure?  I do have this output: "006\n531\n".  You might have caught me on an edit :) Try again, I'm 100% sure of it.

Comment: Yes I get 531 now but is not what I want. It is may impossible as the other guys said. pfffff

Comment: Sry John, did not understand correctly your needs. In this case, do a simple string manipulation: Substring on the ".", Integer.parseInt and String.format("%03d").  Not elegant but, working. ;)

Comment: Yes maybe. Thank you for your time. The point of the exercise is to use a mathematical concept rather than do it with string manipulation. Thanks anyway man